# Symfony2 construct current month

Tags: symfony, datetime

I'm trying to set current month. I tried:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="act_month", type="datetime")
 */
private $actMonth;

public function __construct()
{
  $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M', 'now');
  $this->actMonth = $date;
}
```

Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $this->actMonth = $date->format('M');
}
```

Comment: Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: is $actMonth a DateTime type?

Comment: /**
   * @var \DateTime
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="act_month", type="datetime")
   */
  private $actMonth; ... is it correct?

Comment: yes, but nothing happens. Without format is working correctly. $this->actMonth = new \DateTime()

Comment: Ok, `format` return a string... Thus, you have to type $actMonth as string. /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="act_month", type="string")
 */

Comment: it returns me 0000-00-00 00:00:00 :D

Comment: Did you update schema? `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`

Comment: Your column shouldn't be a `DateTime` object if you're wanting to store an integer. 

Consider changing `@ORM\Column(name="act_month", type="datetime")` to `@ORM\Column(name="act_month", type="integer")`